# CPU usage missing from log for some processes

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get information on all processes and services and save it into a .log.

Here my Problem:
Some processes have noting inside the CPU table, there I want to add something like "Nothing". How can I achieve that?

That is my code so far:

```psh
$ProcessTable = @{Expression={$_.ProcessName};Label="ProcessName";Width=40},
                @{Expression={$_.CPU};Label="CPU";Width=20}
$ServiceTable = @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="Name";Width=40},
                @{Expression={$_.Status};Label="Status";Width=10}

Get-Process |
  Sort-Object CPU -Descending |
  Select-Object ProcessName, CPU |
  Format-Table $ProcessTable |
  Out-File "C:\tmp\prozesse.log"

Get-Service |
  Select-Object Name, Status |
  Format-Table $ServiceTable |
  Out-File "C:\tmp\prozesse.log" -Append

notepad "C:\tmp\prozesse.log"
```

Comment: [Have you seen my answer to a suspiciously similar question from earlier today](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30845404/712649)?

Comment: You should run the script as an Administrator to see all CPU values!

Comment: Yes Mathias and it was said, that this one should be closed and translated to english so i did it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get CPU for some processes because of insufficient rights. You get null value then. To output "Nothing" you have to compare the cpu value with `$null`, something like this:

```
$ProcessTable=@{Expression={$_.ProcessName};Label="ProcessName";Width=40},@{Expression={$cpu=$_.CPU;if($cpu -eq $null){"Nothing";} else {$cpu;}};Label="CPU";Width=20}

$ServiceTable = @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="Name";Width=40},@{Expression={$_.Status};Label="Status";Width=10}
Get-Process | Sort-Object CPU -Descending | Select-Object ProcessName, CPU | format-table $ProcessTable |Out-File "C:\tmp\prozesse.log"
Get-Service | Select-Object Name, Status | Format-Table $ServiceTable | Out-File C:\tmp\prozesse.log -Append
```